# Python Flask - making ALL file uploads go to tmp directory

Tags: python, flask

According to the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/#improving-uploads), Flask stores the uploaded file in-memory if the file is 'reasonably small' (no upper limit mentioned) and otherwise in temporary location as returned by `tempfile.gettempdir()`.

How can I make it store ALL files to the temporary directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a [`Flask` doc](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/docs/patterns/fileuploads.rst#uploading-files), handling of uploading files is actually handled by its underlying [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) WSGI utility library.

As per [werkzeug's documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest._get_file_stream) the lower-limit for getting file's `temp` location, as you mentioned as "reasonably small", is `500KB`.

> The default implementation returns a temporary file if the total content length is higher than 500KB. Because many browsers do not provide a content length for the files only the total content length matters.

Let's look into the upper limit. As per [aforementioned `Flask` doc](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/docs/patterns/fileuploads.rst#uploading-files),

> By default Flask will happily accept file uploads to **an unlimited amount of memory**,but you can limit that by setting the `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` config key.

For example, this code fragment

```
from flask import Flask, Request
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
```

> will limited the maximum allowed payload to 16 megabytes. If a larger file is transmitted, Flask will raise an `werkzeug.exceptions.RequestEntityTooLarge` exception.

**Now, answering your core question**

> How can I make it store ALL files to the temporary directory?

You can do that by overriding [`default_stream_factory()`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/formparser.py#L38) function to this:

```
def default_stream_factory(total_content_length, filename, content_type, content_length=None):
    """The stream factory that is used per default."""
    # if total_content_length > 1024 * 500:
    #    return TemporaryFile('wb+')
    # return BytesIO()
    return TemporaryFile('wb+')
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation :)

Comment: Can I overwrite this function in my `app.py` file?